# #define N 500 error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

I'm trying to sort an array using pointers, but I have this error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric
Here is my code:(programming in C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 500

void sort(int *v, int n){
    int i, j, temp; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) { 

        if (*(v + j) < *(v + i)) { 

            temp = *(v + i); 
            *(v + i) = *(v + j); 
            *(v + j) = temp; 
        } 
      } 
    } 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        printf("%d ", *(v + i)); 
} 

int main()
{
    int N;
    int v[N];
    printf("elements:");
    scanf("%d", v);

    sort(v, N);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int N;` is like `int 500;` - what is the idea? Maybe you very much like the letter N.

Answer (score 5):

`#define N 500` means "please replace any token `N` after this line to `500`", so you cannot use `N` as variable name.

You should remove `int N;` from your `main()` function.

Also `scanf("%d", v);` will read for only first element, not all elements.
You should use a loop to read all elements.

Here is an example of this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (scanf("%d", &v[i]) != 1)
    {
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#define N 500    
int N;
```

both of them have same name, change them

Answer (score 0):

You can use #define NUMBER 500 because NUMBER is a reserved keywords in c language

here :

```
printf("elements:");
scanf("%d", v);
```

why you scan v (v is an array ,you scan the size of array not the array)

you miss '&' in scanf(before the variable)scanf("%d",&x);

'&' allows us to pass the address of variable number which is the place in memory where we store the information that scanf read

my code :

```
#define NUMBER 500

int main()
{
  int v[NUMBER];
  for(int i=0;i<NUMBER;i++)
  {
     scanf("%d",&v[i]);
  }
  sort(v, NUMBER );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not include complete code in the answer. It makes it harder for other to verify your answer. Also if asker fixes something on one of the lines that were same for both of you, then your lines will be out of date. Please [edit] your answer and only include parts of the code that are relevant to your answer.

Comment: @user694733 : that's okey

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int N;
```

expands to

```
int 500;
```

after preprocessing, which is the cause of your error message.

You do not need that separate declaration of `N`, so just remove it.